# Django template not loading Facebook iFrame in Firefox

Tags: django, facebook, iframe

I am trying to load a Facebook Newsfeed iFrame into a Django template using

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href={{ obj.facebook_address }}&tabs=timeline&width=500&height=750&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=true&show_facepile=true&appId=myappid" width="500" height="750" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

This works when browsed with Chrome, but not Firefox or Edge.  With Firefox and Edge I get a Facebook error message

> Your request couldn't be processed
> There was a problem with this request ...

If I take the `src` from the iFrame (ie `https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href={{ obj.facebook_address }}` and post that as the url then I get the iFrame loaded into my Firefox browser so I think it is something to do with my site causing the issue (presumably the headers), but I cannot work out what it is.  Of course, thinking it the headers could be a red herring.

I can get the feed to show if I disable Enhanced Tracking Protection in Firefox, but I cannot believe other sites simply allowing this to slide so I think there must be a solution which doesn't depend on the user amending the settings

I've spent 5 hours trying to work out the issue and I have got nowhere.  Any help much appreciated

Comment: Does the browser console say anything? When you click the shield icon in the address bar, what does that have to say about stuff being blocked?

Comment: It's blocking Facebook tracking content, but it doesn't do this on the development site where the iFrame shows for me (but not a colleague).

Comment: Maybe you have different settings, specifically regarding that dev site then? What does it say on _their_ machine then?

Comment: The only settings is development is set to no-index.  The only difference at the browser is the Enhanced Tracking Protection comes back mauve (saying Facebook tracking) on the production site and grey (saying no trackers) on development.  If I run locally, it comes back mauve

Comment: Then some of your settings regarding tracker blocking must be different, I suppose, otherwise there is no logical explanation why the same thing would behave differently on two otherwise identical sites. Did you maybe add an exception for the dev site at some point? What level do you have the Enhanced Tracking Protection set to in general - Standard, Strict, or Custom?

Comment: I agree something is different, but I cannot understand what.  ETP set to Standard.  This is why I think it must be something in headers and perhaps Facebook doesn't send tracking info when no-index?  But I'm sure others would have come across this.  Also, if I just save the iframe in a file and serve it locally it works fine

Comment: So changing the no-index setting for the dev site for a moment, to verify or disprove that assumption, should be a no-brainer …? (Although I really don’t see what no-index should have to do with whether Facebook wants to render their plugin or not in the first place.)

Comment: Made no difference to dev so must be something else

Comment: From what Facebook receives, the only (main) differences I can think of, would be cookies set for the Facebook domain, and further HTTP headers - so maybe try and compare those in the browser entwork panel, whether you can spot significant difference in what gets send.

Comment: But in general, these days one should treat such plugins the same way as ads - the probability that they will be blocked on the client, is rather high. (Not only due to default tracker blocking implemented by the browser itself, but due to a multitude of privacy-enhancing extensions.) Do not work under the assumption that they will work for everyone, everywhere, and maybe consider fallbacks the user could be pointed to, if they are supposed to receive any essential information this way.

Comment: thanks - also my view, but not the client's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bug on FB side, occured few days ago. We have to be patient and just wait.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2774586826149402/